# Android AudioRecorder read method issue on two mobile device 1)Redmi note 5 pro 2) samsung m10s

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

App start recording  using android AudioRecord. Below is the code for initialized AudioRecord obejct and read data from it using its read method in while loop.In Redmi device loop count and file size is perfect every time but when this code execute on sumsung device loop count  and file size are different.

> Log.d(TAG, "writeAudioDataToFile: "+recordFile.length());
>
> this is approximately 5 sec recording on Samsung device logcat
>
> ```
>    2020-08-14 13:27:47.459 31260-31805/com.example.voicerecord D/WavRecorder: writeAudioDataToFile: 71138592
> ```
>
> this is approximately 5 sec recording on Redmi device logcat
>
> ```
> 2020-08-14 13:28:36.384 23780-23906/com.example.voicerecord D/WavRecorder: writeAudioDataToFile: 491008
> ```
>
> Same code generate different file size.
>
> file size = sampling Rate * sample size * time in sec * channel /8
>
> in this code
> sampling rate = 44100 Hz
> sample size = 16 bit
> time in sec = 5 sec
> channel = 1 for mono
> so redmi device generate right file but Samsung device not . what is
> the solution for sumsung device.

```
 @Override
    public void prepare(String outputFile, int channelCount, int sampleRate, int bitrate) {
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.framesPerVisInterval = (int)((VISUALIZATION_INTERVAL/1000f)/(1f/sampleRate));
        Log.d(TAG, "prepare: channelcount"+channelCount);
        this.channelCount = channelCount;
        recordFile = new File(outputFile);
        if (recordFile.exists() && recordFile.isFile()) {
            int channel = channelCount == 1 ? AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO : 
          AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
            try {
                bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                        channel,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                if (bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR || bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                            channel,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "prepare: "+bufferSize);
                recorder = new AudioRecord(
                        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                        sampleRate,
                        channel,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                        bufferSize
                );
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "sampleRate = " + sampleRate + " channel = " + channel + " bufferSize = " + bufferSize);

                if (recorder != null) {
                    recorder.release();
                }
            }
            if (recorder != null && recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                if (recorderCallback != null) {
                    recorderCallback.onPrepareRecord();
                }
            } else {
                Timber.e("prepare() failed");
                if (recorderCallback != null) {
                    recorderCallback.onError(new RecorderInitException());
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (recorderCallback != null) {
                recorderCallback.onError(new InvalidOutputFile());
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void startRecording() {
        if (recorder != null && recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            if (isPaused) {
                startRecordingTimer();
                recorder.startRecording();
                if (recorderCallback != null) {
                    recorderCallback.onStartRecord(recordFile);
                }
                isPaused = false;
            } else {
                try {
                    recorder.startRecording();
                    isRecording = true;
                    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            writeAudioDataToFile();
                        }
                    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

                    recordingThread.start();
                    startRecordingTimer();
                    if (recorderCallback != null) {
                        recorderCallback.onStartRecord(recordFile);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Timber.e(e, "startRecording() failed");
                    if (recorderCallback != null) {
                        recorderCallback.onError(new RecorderInitException());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        if(isAppend){
            fos = new FileOutputStream(recordFile,true);
        }else{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(recordFile);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Timber.e(e);
        fos = null;
    }
    if (null != fos) {
        int chunksCount = 0;
        ByteBuffer shortBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        shortBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        //TODO: Disable loop while pause.
        while (isRecording) {
            if (!isPaused) {
                if (endProgress == totalProgress) {
                    chunksCount += recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
                    if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != chunksCount) {
                        long sum = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += 2) {
                            //TODO: find a better way to covert bytes into shorts.
                            shortBuffer.put(data[i]);
                            shortBuffer.put(data[i + 1]);
                            sum += Math.abs(shortBuffer.getShort(0));
                            shortBuffer.clear();
                        }
                        lastVal = (int) (sum / (bufferSize / 16));
                        try {
                            fos.write(data);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Timber.e(e);
                            stopRecording();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e(e);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "writeAudioDataToFile: "+recordFile.length());

        setWaveFileHeader(recordFile, channelCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok got the solution. its happen because in my project i use "compile 'org.firezenk:audiowaves:1.1@aar'" this dependancy. i remove it and code is working on both devices.